# Jquery Grid row remains in the edited form saveRow event is called and another row is clicked

Tags: jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I have a grid that is loaded inside a jquery dialog. I have done row editing and row saving  within onSelectRow event. When a row is edited and saved and then another row is clicked, previous row remains in the edited form. I am not able to save and remove the edited form.

Id of my table on which I want to load the grid is MultiCount.

And I have binded the grid inside a function bindShapesGrid(), below is the code.
I have hardcoded a XML String and used it as the data.

function bindShapesgrid() {

```
        var xmlstring = "<root><rows><row><cell>Shortnamevalue</cell><cell>does not equal</cell><cell>and</cell><cell>sad</cell><cell></cell><cell></cell></row><row><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell></cell><cell></cell></row></rows></root>"
        var lastsel2;

        jQuery("#MultiCount").jqGrid({
            datatype: 'xmlstring',
            datastr: xmlstring,
            colNames: ['ShortName', 'Operand 1', 'Value 1', 'AndOr', 'Operand 2', 'Value 2'],
            colModel: [{ name: 'ShortName', index: 'ShortName', align: 'center', width: 80, editable: true, edittype: "select" },
                      { name: 'Operand1', index: 'Operand1', align: 'center', width: 90, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: RetrievegridOperandList() } },
                      { name: 'Value1', index: 'Value1', align: 'center', width: 40, editable: true },
                      { name: 'AndOr', index: 'Refer', align: 'center', width: 80, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "AND:And;OR:Or" } },
                      { name: 'Operand2', index: 'Operand2', align: 'center', width: 80, edittype: "select", editable: true, editoptions: { value: RetrievegridOperandList() } },
                      { name: 'Value2', index: 'Value2', align: 'center', width: 40, editable: true }],

            root: 'rows',
            row: 'row',


            celledit: true,
            sortname: 'ShortName',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            height: "100%",
            rowNum: 10,



            onSelectRow: function (id) {

                          if (id && id !== lastsel2) {

                         jQuery('#MultiCount').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                         jQuery("#MultiCount").jqGrid('saveRow', lastsel2, true);

                          lastsel2 = id;
                                }
                            }

                  });

            }
```